# Python: parsing help needed!

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to retrieve certain fields within a .lua file. Initially I thought I could just split on commas but the second set of curly brackets ruins that. An example:

```
return { 
    { 6163, 0, "tv", false, {1302}, "ESPN Deportes", "ESPN Deportes es el", nil,"tv","936",nil,"4x3", mediaRestrictions={"m2g" } },
    { 57075, 0, "tv", false, {1302}, "Video Rola", "Video \"Música Para Tus Ojos\", uedes ver.", nil,"tv","948",nil,"4x3", mediaRestrictions={"m2g" } },
    { 717242, 0, "tv", false, {1302,1301,1288}, "Hits", "asdlfj", nil,"cliplinear","6310",nil,"4x3", mediaRestrictions={"m2g" } },
    { 122719, 0, "tv", false, {1302,1301,1288}, "Bombone", "asdf", nil,"tv","74",nil,"4x3", mediaRestrictions={"m2g" } },
}
```

So I would be looking for the following from the first line:
"ESPN Deportes"(6th field), tv(9th), 936(10th)

God help me...or more likely a stackoverflow ninja. (Python)

---

### Updated with solution

Solution as graciously provided by S.Mark:

```
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

# Hackisly transform the lua into json
data = re.sub('\w+=', '', data)
data = data.replace("return","")
data = data.replace("{","[").replace("}","]")
data = data.replace("nil","null")
data = data.replace(",]","]")
data = json.loads(data.strip())
```

Comment: http://niemeyer.net/lunatic-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably convert to json.

```
import json

text = r"""return { 
{ 6163, 0, "tv", false, {1302}, "ESPN Deportes", "ESPN Deportes es el", nil,"tv","936",nil,"4x3", mediaRestrictions={"m2g" } },
{ 57075, 0, "tv", false, {1302}, "Video Rola", "Video \"Música Para Tus Ojos\", uedes ver.", nil,"tv","948",nil,"4x3", mediaRestrictions={"m2g" } },
{ 717242, 0, "tv", false, {1302,1301,1288}, "Hits", "asdlfj", nil,"cliplinear","6310",nil,"4x3", mediaRestrictions={"m2g" } },
{ 122719, 0, "tv", false, {1302,1301,1288}, "Bombone", "asdf", nil,"tv","74",nil,"4x3", mediaRestrictions={"m2g" } },
}"""

obj = json.loads(text.replace("return","").replace("mediaRestrictions=","").replace("{","[").replace("}","]").replace("nil","null").replace("\n","").replace(",]","]").strip())

print obj

# [[6163, 0, u'tv', False, [1302], u'ESPN Deportes', u'ESPN Deportes es el', None, u'tv', u'936', None, u'4x3', [u'm2g']], [57075, 0, u'tv', False, [1302], u'Video Rola', u'Video "M\xfasica Para Tus Ojos", uedes ver.', None, u'tv', u'948', None, u'4x3', [u'm2g']], [717242, 0, u'tv', False, [1302, 1301, 1288], u'Hits', u'asdlfj', None, u'cliplinear', u'6310', None, u'4x3', [u'm2g']], [122719, 0, u'tv', False, [1302, 1301, 1288], u'Bombone', u'asdf', None, u'tv', u'74', None, u'4x3', [u'm2g']]]

for x in obj:
  print x[5], x[8], x[9]

#ESPN Deportes tv 936
#Video Rola tv 948
#Hits cliplinear 6310
#Bombone tv 74
```

Comment: You're a get things done kind of guy I can tell. Thanks man, good stuff!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not experienced in lua but I'm guessing you're receiving that as a string/file.

Not the best solution:

```
import json
myvalue = "{ 1,2,3, { 4,5,6}, {7} }"
myvalue = myvalue.replace("{", "[").replace("}", "]")
mylist = json.loads(myvalue)
```

And then deal with it as a list?

Or if it is a file use `json.load` instead of `json.loads`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this trick:

1. remove 'return' from the string
2. replace `{` and `}` with `[` and `]`
3. run the `eval` (or `ast.literal_eval`, which is safer) on the string to obtain a list of lists
4. get the elements you want

Comment: literal_eval is genious. In python 2.7+ you could even drop step 2, since set literals is added. In any case however, this does not work because, among other things, `mediaRestrictions={"m2g" }` is not a valid set or list item.